# Why do many mobile GPUs support OpenGL ES, but not OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es, gpu

For instance, out of the entire ARM Mali line, many GPUs support OpenGL ES 3+, Direct3D 9+ (some support up to 11/12), and some support Vulkan, but none support OpenGL, not even newer versions of OpenGL that deprecated the fixed pipeline. Same thing with Adreno.

Is the hardware incapable of supporting full GL (if so, why?), or did the driver developers just not implement it?

Comment: Because OpenGL ES _was made_ for those kind of devices.

Comment: "*that deprecated the fixed pipeline*" *Removed*, not deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because OpenGL ES was created exactly to target "embedded" hardware.

On the other hand, the idea of creating OpenGL ES as a separate standard instead of being just a "subset" of OpenGL (today we would call it a "profile", if you want) was a very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very bad idea.

The major implication that you're facing here is that, in order to implement OpenGL support in addition to OpenGL ES, vendors would need to develop another *similar but subtly different* GL library. And that means extra development effort, testing, certification. So, for them, it's far easier to push this effort onto developers and ask them to create different renderers, targeting OpenGL on desktop and OpenGL ES on embedded.

(Luckily, if you have OpenGL, this mess is somehow "simplified" by the `GL_ARB_ESx_compatibility` extensions, that allow you to have some OpenGL ES datatypes / calls / features, so you're able to re-use more code.)

Apart from this, you're right -- if the hardware supports Vulkan, then it would support OpenGL 4.5 / DX12. Roughly speaking, each of this line targets a different hardware generation:

- OpenGL 2.1 (+ FBOs) | OpenGL ES 2 | Direct3D 9
- OpenGL 3.3 | OpenGL ES 3.0/3.1 | Direct3D 10
- OpenGL 4 | OpenGL ES 3.2 | Direct3D 11

Plus a line which would look like "OpenGL 4.5 | Vulkan | Direct3D 12".

(Yes, the OpenGL ES version numbers don't even make sense and don't match the OpenGL ones, I assume so that vendors are not scared by having to jump a major number and instead see them as "incremental" changes, although ES 3.2 requires way more silicon than 3.0)

In practice the devil is in the details, so you've got f.i. tessellation in OpenGL ES 3.2 but in OpenGL 4.0, but compute shaders were already in OpenGL ES 3.1 but in OpenGL got introduced later -- 4.3 --, and other levels of such crazyness.

Comment: "*if the hardware supports Vulkan, then it would support OpenGL 4.5 / DX12.*" Here's a partial list of things which Vulkan does not require that GL 4.5 does: Atomic counters, Transform feedback, indexing interface blocks by dynamically uniform indices, indexing arrays of opaque types by dynamically uniform indices, geometry shaders, tessellation shaders. I can keep going, but my point is clear. A Vulkan implementation that supported *all* of Vulkan's optional parts might be equivalent to 4.5 (except for TF and counters). But Vulkan makes many things optional that are mandatory for GL 4.5.

Comment: Ah, so essentially, the hardware is capable of supporting OpenGL, but the ROI is too low for the vendor to bother.

Comment: Also, your "rough" hardware equivalents aren't valid. Microsoft effectively controlled the IHV market on desktop machines, so each "generation" was based primarily on features that Microsoft negotiated between all the IHVs. In the mobile space, hardware generations were never so rigidly enforced with ES.

Comment: @NicolBolas: so the only thing that effectively is required by Vulkan is command buffers (a concept introduced in ~GL4), and a pipeline which is basically the GL2 / GLES2 one? Is this just a theorical thing or does such hardware exist in practice (so far everything I've seen is actually fully GLES3.2/GL4.5). About the control of the market: sure Microsoft did what was most convenient for it back then, but that doesn't make the analogy not stand (?)

Comment: @peppe: "*command buffers (a concept introduced in ~GL4)*" OpenGL never had command buffers. The closest you would get is NV_command_list, which is a proprietary extension. "*a pipeline which is basically the GL2 / GLES2 one*" If you ignore compute shaders, image load/store, SSBOs, input attachments, image views, array textures, and the entire renderpass system, then yes, Vulkan is basically the same as ES 2.0.

Comment: "*so far everything I've seen is actually fully GLES3.2/GL4.5*" According to the Vulkan database, the only hardware that supports, for example, [tessellation shaders](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?feature=tessellationShader) is desktop hardware. That may just be the database not being frequently updated for newer mobile drivers, Vulkan implementations still being in beta, or other stuff. But that's the data I have available.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly that accurate. For instance NVIDIA's Tegra K1 supports Vulkan (and GL4.5); ARM Mali T760/T860/T880 support Vulkan (and GLES 3.2). Those are all SoCs or GPUs made for SoC integration. Is it another case of vendors pushing Vulkan only on the ultra-performant hardware?

Answer (score 4):

Until Desktop OpenGL jettisoned the fixed-function crap with GL 3.1, it would be unreasonable for IHVs to implement it. Even after this, there was a much bigger problem: they couldn't handle it.

For example, GL 3.1 requires support for uniform buffer objects. That was in early 2009. No version of ES provided such things until ES 3.0 in 2014; by then, desktop GL was at version 4.5.

The thing you have to understand is that mobile and desktop hardware have evolved at different rates and times. Versions of OpenGL were designed to expose the features of hardware available on desktop GPUs of that era. Similarly, an OpenGL ES version exposed some common subset of what mobile hardware of that era could do. The long dominance of ES 2.0 was primarily because there was a lack of consensus on what major hardware providers would actually support.

As such, each API is intended to be implemented on a specific set of hardware, and therefore is blind to the needs of hardware outside that area of focus. It has only been quite recently that any mobile GPU could support *all* of the features of a version of desktop GL. Even so, they still evolved in a very different way.

GL 3.2, for example, requires support for Geometry Shaders. That was in 2009. OpenGL ES didn't see that feature become a *requirement* until ES 3.2 shipped in 2015. Not only that, tessellation shaders (and a bunch more features) became core in ES 3.2, which in desktop GL were 4.0.

By contrast, ES 3.1 requires compute shaders and image load/store functionality. These only showed up in desktop GL in 4.3 and 4.2, respectively.

Which means that if mobile hardware that was limited to ES 3.1 functionality wanted to expose their hardware through desktop GL... how could they do it? They couldn't use any desktop GL version 3.2 or greater, since those require GS's and their GPU doesn't have those. But their GPU can handle compute shaders and image load/store, which are only core in higher GL versions.

They would be restricted to desktop GL 3.1 + extensions.

The two APIs diverged in order to fulfill the needs of their particular platforms. Their separate lines of hardware evolution have only recently begun to converge into a reasonable common subset.

Which is why it is now when we find that both APIs are being *replaced* (and by an API that, by design, can run on both sets of hardware through the use of features) Why bother spending the effort on something that will quickly become irrelevant?